# Sensors not finding fan only showing CPU

Tags: linux, fan, lenovo-laptop, ubuntu-14.04, temperature

I have a lenovo yoga 2 with ubuntu 14.04 but when I run sensors this is the output

```
$:~# sudo sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +61.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +59.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +59.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +58.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

When I run `lspci -v` this is the output

```
$  lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: hsw_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at b0518000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 0a03 (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at b0510000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41
    Memory at b0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at b0520000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at b051c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: b0400000-b04fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] #00
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at b0524000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
    I/O ports at 3088 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 3094 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 3080 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 3090 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 3060 [size=32]
    Memory at b0523000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at b0521000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 3040 [size=32]

00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series Thermal (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at b0522000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-

01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at b0400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 28-b2-bd-ff-ff-74-a7-7a
    Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [154] Vendor Specific Information: ID=cafe Rev=1 Len=014 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

I ran `sensors-detect` again and restarted the `kmod`

Can't seem to figure out why I can't find fan speed

**EDIT:**
Here is the output for `sensors-detect`

```
Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)yes
Successful!

Monitoring programs won't work until the needed modules are
loaded. You may want to run 'service kmod start'
to load them.

Unloading cpuid... OK
```

Comment: You can't find the fan speed because the necessary modules for *sensors* that can read the fan speed are not enabled (or there are no modules that know how to deal with your hardware). What's the output of sensors-detect? Anything on the SMBus that looks like a fan controller?

Comment: The two "signal processing controllers" also look suspicious, they seem related to the "Intel® Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Driver", but it's the first time I've come across these.

Comment: @dirkt I have gone ahead and added the output.  I can't seem to find anything that seems like a fan controller

Comment: You haven't posted the interesting part, which would be everything before "Now follows a summary", because that would show (1) if it checked for the "signal processing controllers" at all, and (2) which devices are on the SMBUS (assuming you said "YES" when asked to check it).

Comment: @dirkt was too long here it is in a gist https://gist.github.com/nadermx/11e0a0bb8f441c666eb960d11b2ade87

Comment: That's again not the full output, but at least it shows that there's quite a number of clients on the SMBUS (but apparently none of them is recognized). So it could still be a device on the SMBUS, or the "signal processing controller". I would have suggested to contact the lm-sensors project mailing list directly (with the **full** output), and ask them if there are any drivers for these particular sensors/fans, or if they can identify them, but it seems like the site (http://www.lm-sensors.org/) is dead. So I don't really know what to suggest.